# How To Make Multiple Parallel SOAP Requests in Python

Tags: python, soap, parallel-processing

I need to make a lot (~10000) daily requests via SOAP. The way their servers are set up I can't batch the requests, but instead need to make each request individually. However I can make many simultaneous requests.

The basic pattern that I'm using is:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

ids = client.get_available_ids()
pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
results = [mp.apply_async(download, args=(client, x)) for x in ids]
data = [y.get(timeout=1) for y in results]

def download(client, reference):
    response = client.get_data(reference)
    return response
```

Where `client` is a `suds.Client()`.

This fails though when I try to call `get()` on the results, with the following error message:

```
suds.MethodNotFound: Method not found: 'ReferenceDataService.WSHttpBinding_ReferenceSearchService.__getinitargs__'
```

This error isn't thrown when I make each call in series.

Can I make multiple parallel SOAP calls in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. The root cause in my case was that my code was attempting to cache the result of the call, specifically when the caching layer attempts to serialize the result. The result contains a reference to the `suds.Client` and the attempt to serialize that tries to call `__getinitargs__()` on the `suds.Client.service` object. The suds code then attempts to find a method with that name in the service's WSDL definition, but cannot and consequently raises an exception.

From what you've described, this may have no similarity. Nonetheless, it seems worth sharing just in case it does or another person stumbles onto this question. =)

Here's some reference I found useful on [serialization in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances).